# Ruby grab index of first element of an array that matches criteria

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

I ran across this issue and am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Given the array:

```
options = [
  SelectItem.new(-1, "String 1"),
  SelectItem.new(0, "String 2"),
  SelectItem.new(7, "String 3"),
  SelectItem.new(14, "String 4")
]
```

What is the best way to grab the index of the first element that matches a certain criteria?

My solution was:

```
my_index = 0
options.each_with_index do |o, index|
  if o.value == some_value
    my_index = index
    break
  end
end
```

**Is there another way to do this?** `Enumerable#find` returns the first object that satisfies the condition, but I want something that returns the index of the first object that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Where does that `index` in the block come from?

Comment: Sorry, that was `each_with_index`. I mistyped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a=[100,200,300]
a.index{ |x| x%3==0 }   # returns 2
```

for your case:

```
options.index{ |o| o.value == some_value }
```

Comment: If you're only checking if two objects are equal, you can use `options.index(some_value)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#index`

```
> a = ['asdf', 'qwer', '1234']
> a.index { |e| e =~ /\d/ }
=> 2
```